# Angularjs reloading a page with route paramter variables

Tags: php, angularjs

I am using laravel framework for back-end and angularjs as the front-end framework , the application I'm working on let the user edit some content by redirecting them to the relative url with the specific content id , it works perfectly when user click's on the edit button and redirected to the page with route parameter variable but if the user try to refresh/reload on the same page for example BASE_URL + 'edit-files/14' the page will not load anymore.

Here is my code :

```
App.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/edit-files/:id',{
        templateUrl:BASE_URL+'/public/templates/states/billboard/pages/edit-files.html',
        controller:'editfilesController'
    })
```

I use $location.path for redirecting to edit page on the main controller :

```
$scope.editPhoto = function(contentId){
// redirecting to edit page and posting the content id
    $location.path('/edit-files/' + contentId);
}
```

and this is my code for retrieving the route parameter and send it to laravel to fetch the database records :

```
App.controller('editfilesController',function($http,$scope,$location,$routeParams){
$scope.id = $routeParams.id;
var data = {
    'id':$scope.id
};
$http({
    method: 'post',
    url: BASE_URL + '/content/edit',
    data: data,
    headers:{'Content-type': 'application/json'}
})
```

});

Comment: What was the error that you got?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like problem is with configuration your routes. Try to leave just

```
..
templateUrl: '/public/templates/states/billboard/pages/edit-files.html',
..
```

Comment: I tried that still got the problem , error on the console is this :
`Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16 <div class="ng-scope" ng-include="template.url">`
and the code on the index.php is this (which I think is the cause of the problem)  :
`<head>
..few definitions here
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppController" ng-class="[header.menu_style, header.header_topbar, header.effect]" class="animated" >

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
 <div ng-include="template.url"></div>
</div>
</body>`